# Phaser hovering over event

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am new to phaser and I am trying to create a "hovering over" event. That is, when the mouse hover over an object, it shows something. Here is the code:

```
var hoverPS, hoverEG, hoverAQI, AQIBar, ecoBar, pubBar;
var Game = {
    create: function () {
        this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'game-bg');
        this.add.button(30, 7, 'home-btn', this.home, this);
        AQIBar = game.add.sprite(136, 19, 'AQI-bar');
        ecoBar = game.add.sprite(348, 19, 'eco-bar');
        pubBar = game.add.sprite(583, 19, 'pub-bar');
        hoverAQI = game.add.sprite(95, 45, 'hover-AQI');
        AQIBar.inputEnabled = true;
        AQIBar.events.onInputOver.add(over, this);
        AQIBar.events.onInputOut.add(out, hoverAQI);

    },
}
```

Now I am getting an error saying that for this line

```
AQIBar.events.onInputOver.add(over, this);
```

I got this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: over is not defined.

Can someone help with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Define function `over` like this or as you like

```
function over(item) {

    item.fill = "#ffff44";
    item.text = "clicked " + clicks + " times";

}
```

Comment: I believe in this case it would be `over: function(item) { ... }`.